# jQuery find children

Tags: jquery

hi i have a question about some jquery
how do i select "First-First" of my html structure, when the mouse enter's main ?
html structure:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="first-first"></div>
        <div class="first-second"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

would this be the prober way of doing it ?

```
  $("div.main").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).child(".first").next(".first-first").show();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).child(".first").next(".first-first").hide();
  });
```

Comment: Not really, `$(this).find(".first-first").show();` is enough assuming you have only one.

Comment: @ShadowWizard `.find()` is slow.  Marnix's answer is faster and has the same effect.

Comment: @tandu as far as I know it's just alias that does exactly the same behind the scenes. Can you prove otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
$("#main").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.first-first', this).show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.first-first', this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a simple selector:

```
$("div.main").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".first > .first-first", this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
  $("div.main").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).children(".first").children(".first-first").show();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children(".first").children(".first-first").hide();
  });
```

Or even faster:

```
  $("div.main").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find(".first-first").show();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find(".first-first").hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#main').mouseenter(function() {
   $("div.first div.first-first", this).show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
     $("div.first div.first-first", this).hide();
});
```

this will do

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.main div:first div:first").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('.first-first').show();
```

You should use `find()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that. And you should probally use [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) not [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

```
 $("div.main").mouseover(function() {
        $(".first-first").show();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".first-first").hide();
  });
```